# Filter a generic list based on a reflected value of its entries with linq

Tags: linq, reflection

I have a generic list of objects from which I want to whittle down based on a reflected value within it

```
List<MyCaseObj> CasesInGroup = ....;
PropertyInfo piItem = typeof(MyCaseObj).GetProperty(SomePropertyName).PropertyType.GetProperty(SomeValueMemberName);

    var CasesToProcess = (from csh in CasesInGroup 
        where ((Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(csh, null), null))
            .In(fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID)) 
                select csh);
```

however it transpires that the particular value may sometimes be null, and the In extension is not to fond of that throwing a 'Non-static method requires a target.' exception

adding a && (Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(csh, null), null) != null doesn't work, and does the reflection twice anyway which doesnt seem right in the first place even if it did..
could someone explain how to get around this, or maybe just a nicer way to do this in the first place.

any help, pointers or such would be gratefully recieved

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace

```
(Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(csh, null), null))
```

with

```
(csh != null ? (Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(csh, null), null)) : Guid.Empty)
```

which should work unless `Items` sometimes contains `Guid.Empty`.

P.S. If you are up for learning something very, very cool, convert this expression to a lambda:

```
var myCaseType = typeof(MyCaseObj);
var param = Expression.Parameter(myCaseType);
var cond = Expression.Condition(
    Expression.NotEqual(param, Expression.Constant(null, myCaseType))
,   Expression.Property(param, "SomePropertyName")
,   Expression.Constant(Guid.Empty)
);
var lambda = (Func<MyCaseObj,Guid>)Expression.Lambda(cond, param).Compile();
```

You can now re-write your select like this:

```
var CasesToProcess = (from csh in CasesInGroup 
    where lambda(csh)In(fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID)) 
    select csh);
```

Comment: lol, sure would always like to learn something cool, however.. 
a. can sort of see what is going on there but not entirely
b. does that actually handle the fac the the property I am after is sort of 2 deep?
c. a sort of aside - would fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID).Contains(..) be faster than the In extension
pps fld is inside a loop thus:foreach (BackingSheetGroupField fld in bsg.Fields) and the SomePropertyname and SomevalueMemeberName come from within that.. not sure if compiling that on each lap would be a large overhead?

Comment: @nat a. The code builds a representation of the expression using LINQ Expression. b. You are right, I missed the two-deep entirely - did not scroll to the right to see it in the OP. Adding a second level of indirection is a great exercise: if you manage to do it, you'll know that you understand what's going on far better than "sort of". c. I have no idea of the relative speed of the two - you may want to run a quick experiment to see which one wins.

Comment: for now as I am in a rush I ended up with
CasesToProcess = CasesInGroup.Where(
c => fld.Items.Select(i => i.ItemID).Contains(
(c != null ? (Guid)piItem.GetValue(piField.GetValue(c, null), null) : Guid.Empty)));
will do some reading though, thanks muchly